# Entity Framework returns empty data for a local database that shows data in SQL Server Object Explorer

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, localdb

I am writing Integration tests for a WPF application and I'm using a local database that is placed inside the solution for integration testing and this database has data inside it.

When I read data from this database after connecting it to SQL Server, it returns valid data, but once I go back to the application, add its connection string and try to get data, the code returns an empty set. I'm on a tight deadline and I don't know why this is happening.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Simple code is:

```
var xsystem = context.Species.ToList();
```

My connection string is:

```
<add name="MaxDatabase" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=Catalog=MaxLocalEmbeded;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just  replace your connection string with this below code.
 Also remove "catalog=catalog" from your connection.

```
<add name="MaxDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MaxLocalEmbeded;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MaxLocalEmbeded.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked but what do you think is the logic behind it? what If I want the connection string to be generic so that if the local db is pushed to source control no one has to change the connection string again and again?

Comment: change your connection string Data Source To server  and server value should be "." like below connection string

 connectionString="Server=.;Initial Catalog=MaxLocalEmbeded;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MaxLocalEmbeded.mdf"

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I'm looking for the logic behind it, why do we have to attach a database file with its exact path in the directory? can't we make it generic?

Comment: its fully dynamic i think.

Comment: how will this `|DataDirectory|` will be replaced then? if it is dynamic.